# colorbox not loading images in lightbox

Tags: javascript

I have dloaded libraries 7.x-2.0 in my modules folder and installed colorbox 7.x-2.2 in modules and installed  1.3.26 plugin to sites/all/libraries folder and enabled colorbox in manage display for fields. ALL OF THIS WAS WORKING BEFORE UPGRADE. So started from scratch but when I click on an image it opens lightbox and the image never loads.

Comment: anything in your logs, also you clear the cache. Any recently module that it was installed and apply like display suite. Did you check in  the manage display of the content type?

Comment: I've reinstalled now for the fourth time, cleared caches everything. The only thing that has changed since it was working last is an upgrade in colorbox for which I used drush but now installed manually and no reported errors. Just as I say, the image will not load in the lightbox. Could this be a file path problem? I haven't changed any file paths...or I noticed in colorbox settings it lists add/node/* as one of pages not to be displayed? I'm completely confused and have had to put site in maintenance mode for long time now. Only launched site yesterday.

Comment: it might sounds like a silly question...bud did you check the permissions of your images files in your server? What I would suggest is to download the site to your computer and see if I have the same issues there reggarding to permission.

Comment: cayerdis...not silly at all. drwxrwx--- 12 apache root  4096 Jan 24 13:56 files
but def this has to do with some kind of override in settings where can't view files. still haven't fixed it.

Comment: http://drupal.home.com/admin/config/media/file-system
Message Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in drupal_mkdir() (line 2341 of /var/www/html/drupal/includes/file.inc).

Comment: It sounds like an issues with your tmp. Some people fixed in here http://drupal.org/node/1463844

Comment: i have a bigger problem now after editing settings.php and tried chmod 640 then get locked out of site as it wants to run update.php

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the colorbox plugin uses a different version string in its js file ( `sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js` ) so it doesnt get recognised by the colorbox module requirements check.

If possible look at the version string from the previous file, it's the first line, and copy that over, incrementing the number in the new file.

Comment: in the js or min.js ? sorry which part do i copy over please David..

Comment: Both files, but especially min.js, just the version information to first line

Comment: will give it a go, thx and report back.

Comment: /*
        jQuery ColorBox v1.3.26
        (c) 2013 Jack Moore - jacklmoore.com/colorbox
        updated: 2013-01-23
        license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

Comment: this part needs replacing ?

Comment: with this :// ColorBox v1.3.20.2 - jQuery lightbox plugin
// (c) 2012 Jack Moore - jacklmoore.com
// License: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

Comment: PLEASE I NEED HELP- SOMEONE!

Comment: Hi Ann, sorry I was on mobile before, did changing the version number help? You'll also need the colorbox js files at the correct path in `sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js`

Comment: David, i had to lie down it was starting to be too upsetting after 8 hours straight and no still not fixed.

Comment: if i use drush colorbox-plugin command it installs without extra colorbox folder

Comment: if you get a moment could u pls post exactly how to change vs number for js files- i'm unsure of what to do.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1890116 looks like have to apply a patch but how?